# Pandas, Validating data, check if all groups are with the same length

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following DF:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  4  3
3  4  3
4  5  6
5  5  6
6  5  6
```

After grouping with column `A` I get 3 groups

```
(1,    A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2)
(4,    A  B
2  4  3
3  4  3)
(5,    A  B
4  5  6
5  5  6
6  5  6)
```

I would like to count the groups different from a specific row count, for example 2 as an input will result 1 as an output because there is only 1 group with 3 rows, were 3 as input will output 2 for the other groups.

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
```

---

```
2  4  3
3  4  3
```

---

```
4  5  6
5  5  6
6  5  6
```

What is the Pandas solution for such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with test not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and then count number of `True`s by `sum`:

```
N = 2
a = df['A'].value_counts().ne(N).sum()
print (a)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count values, then filter on `B`:

```
counts = df.groupby('A').count()
count_input = 2

print(len(counts[counts['B'] != count_input]))
```